# QTABLEVIEW setSpan sometimes some sperate-lines disappears

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm trying to use `QTABLEVIEW::setSpan()` to make a table with some cells nearby merged into one,but sometimes it comes out correctly, sometimes some seperate-lines disappear,don't know why.i doubted that the reason is that what the data it showed last time disturbed the result of next time,and what i'm using now is   `QStandardItemModel::clear()` to remove the result of last time before showing.is there any other reliable way to clear the result of last time thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some more code?

Do you use your `QTabelView` like [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43611-How-to-use-setSpan-in-QTableView):

```
QTableView view;
view.setModel(model);
view.setSpan(0, 0, 1, model->columnCount());
view.show();
```

Comment: yes,kindof that.
pTableModel->setItem(org1,0,new QStandardItem(strSat));
mpAutoEvaluateTable->setSpan(org1,0,ind-org1,1);